# Pimcore: why I can't see assets after instalation?

Tags: xampp, pimcore

After instalation of Pimcore and logging in into admin account I can't see image assets:

[image: Screenshoot of issue]

I tried both demo and skeleton install package and the issue is the same on both instances.

I am using Xampp 3.2.4 (Apache and MySQL) on Windows 10.

**What I have tried**

1. Since the problem occurs on both Pimcore installations (demo and skeleton), I figured the problem was with the Apache user access settings for the assets folder. So I went to my assets folder (../project-name/web/var/assets) and checked permission in settings (left click on assets folder > properties > security). Giving full control to all users didn't helped.
2. Second thing I've tried was checking if Pimcore system requirements are checked (especialy imagick and gd extensions). So I went to Pimcore console and run *pimcore:system:requirements:check* command. And every thing seems fine: [image: PHP extensions check]
3. Last thing I've tried was changing in *httpd.conf* in  section to "*Require all granted*" but it didn't help.

Also, if I go to assets folder on my computer, files are there and I can open them normaly, so they are not missing.

PS. I'm not a developer, I need local instalation of Pimcore to learn content creation. So keep that in mind :)

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, it did not helped.

Comment: In case someone has a similar problem (working with Pimcore on Windows): There was some workaround added to the Pimcore Imagick Adapter to work with paths containing colons. This breaks all paths containing drive letters. Go to vendor\pimcore\pimcore\lib\Image\Adapter\Imagick.php, line 102 and comment out the following: $imagePathLoad = ':' . $imagePathLoad;

Answer (score 0):

In Pimcore Admin open the `Settings -> Thumbnails -> Image Thumbnails` .
In this section you can define ratios for images and how the should be resized.

Click on the `add` button, name your thumbnail setting properly and click save.
You can now define a transformation you like, e.g. Resize. This allows you to resize images with a fixed with.

After creating some settings navigate to your projects root via console and enter the commands to clear the image thumbnail cache and optimize the images

`bin/console pimcore:thumbnails:clear`

`bin/console pimcore:thumbnails:optimize-images`

[Pimcore 6 Documentation](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Assets/Working_with_Thumbnails) gives you a detailed overview on how to use this feature and set multiple ways to generate thumbnails.